# In how many ways can $20$ mice be distributed to five boxes so that each box gets exactly $4$ of them?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a simple problem that I am working on:

We have 5 boxes and have to arrange 20 mice in a way that each box gets exactly 4 of them (i.e. 4 in each box) .

boxes are distinguishable and 20 mice are indistinguishable.

Is this is a combination problem, since 20/4 = 5 pairs one for each box mean C(5,5)  = 1 ?

Added in explanation: order of the mice doesn't matter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, is there any order that must be followed?

Comment: Factorials and permutations are basically the same, loosely speaking. They both require order. However, combinations does not.

Comment: Consider a different problem.  $9$ mice in $3$ boxes.  How many ways are there of choosing $3$ mice for box-1?  Once that is done, how many ways are there of choosing $3$ of the remaining mice for box-2?

Comment: If the mice would be distinguishable, then the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) would answer your question as ${20 \choose 4,4,4,4,4}$. But if the mice are indistinguishable as you say, then there is only one way to arrange, which is to put 4 mice in each box.

Comment: @Momo Good point.  I suspect that the OP (i.e. original poster) has a typo in his question.  Otherwise the problem becomes trivial.